# Use database for persistent caching in fastAPI for async functions

Tags: caching, fastapi

I have a service which runs a fastAPI app.
The service makes some calls to OpenAI and a significant ratio of the calls are equal thus it makes sense to cache the calls.

The issue is that I run multiple instances of the app (say 4), thus using an async_lru cache only caches the call to each specific instance, and not across the instances.

I can find some persitent caches e.g `joblib.Memory` but that does not seem to support async-calls out of the box nor using a database for storing calls/returns.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Query your database or something like redis with a key (the query) and see if a result gets returned - if not, make the query to openai.

Comment: Yeah, I also got that answer from ChatGPT, but that requires a Redis-server running, which is a last resort

Comment: Use your database as the backend in that case?